# Table style disappears after adding a row

Tags: python-3.x, openxml, docx, python-docx, word-style

I'm using python-docx to populate a word template that I have
The problem is that, I want to apply a particular style to a table  I have
The table exists already
and I'm just extending it like this:

```py
document = Document(path_to_my_docx)
table = document.tables[0]
row = table.add_row()
row.cells[0].text = "amrouna "
```

But when I add the row, it outputs this
[image]
the row containing amrouna is the row I added
I read in the python docx documentation, that styles won't apply unless they already exist in the document
which is the case here, isn't it ? because my table is already styled before I even load/modify it
Does anyone know how to either:

1. keep the style from changing when adding a row
2. Apply the same style to the table once everything is finished

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the text of the **cell** object, it will override any styling applied to the table/row/cell/etc. What I found out after much struggle w/ something similar, is that you have to replace the text of the **run** within the **paragraph**, within the **cell**.

```
row.cells[0].paragraphs[0].runs[0].text = "amrouna "
```

This will preserve the styling from my limited experience... Hopefully it works for you as well.